# What process do you go through when creating a typeface to make sure that it is not too similar to something that already exists?

Tags: fonts, typefaces, design-process

From the comments and answers I received from a previous question ([How much alteration to a font constitutes a new variation?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35330/how-much-alteration-to-a-font-constitutes-a-new-variation/71661?noredirect=1#comment109470_71661)) I thought that this might actually be a more constructive and practical question to ask since it gives people some idea of the things that they need to check for to make sure that the typeface that they create is not too close to something that already exists and might be seen as simply 'copying' or 'modifying' an existing typeface slightly.